# Performance testing a Flex client

Tags: performance, apache-flex, testing, ria

While I have used performance test tools for a number of years now, they all operate at the network level, recording traffic between the client and server.

Most of the time, managers are interested in the performance that the end user sees.

With RIA applications such as Flex, part of the performance that the user sees is comprised of calculations etc on the client desktop itself. But most tools do not record that time.

Some RIAs include a profiler, but the profiler is only simulating one client.

Has anyone found a good solution to this? The best idea I can come up with is to have a network level tool (e.g. Neoload) creating load on the server, then using either a profiler or some GUI-automation to record full client times. This seems a bit clunky though.

Thanks,

Gordon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an extension for Selenium to test Flex UI:
http://code.google.com/p/flex-ui-selenium/

Comment: Thanks Seba - do you agree with me then that the best approach to the problem would be a network tool and then a GUI tool on top?

Comment: As your topic was "Testing the Flex Client" I guess you want to perform UI tests. Selenium is a quite good testing tool for UI. Unfortunately UI testing always is kind of tricky. I can see also that there are JUnit tools like http://www.flexunit.org/ however if that applies to the specific use-cases that you would like to test I can hardly judge. I think the best testing framework is the one that fits your needs. That can be either a network testing tool or anything else, depending on your use cases.

Answer (score 3):

There's a larger number of tools available for testing the overall performance of a Flex application, and the majority focus on network communication performance (mostly AMF for larger apps) and the load tests for the backend.

Here's a short list of some tools or services:

- http://www.spoon.as/ecosystem/testing-load-and-performance/
- http://www.genilogix.com/products-hp-performance.aspx / Article: [Performance Testing Flex Applications using LoadRunner](http://softwaretesttips.com/2011/11/21/performance-testing-flex-applications-using-loadrunner/)

When you are testing a client application, there are a number of parameters to test:

- Application load and initialization time
- Framerate
- Memory consumption
- Impact of garbage collection / System.pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent() API
- Check if application is using hardware acceleration (GPU) (can improve graphics performance drastically, but has some drawbacks as well)

Here are some links which should be useful:

- [Flash Builder Profiler (commercial)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0169-8000.html)
- [Adobe TV: Measuring Framerate Performance](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/codedependent/measuring-frame-rate-performance/)
- [Adobe article: Garbage collection internals for Flash Player and Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/garbage-collection.html)
- [Providing Hints to the Garbage Collector in AIR](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2011/10/providing-hints-to-the-garbage-collector-in-air-3.html) 3
- [DemonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/) Great for debugging and CPU profiling
- [The Miner (formerly Flash Preload Profiler)](http://jpauclair.net/FlashPreloadProfiler/) / [*The Miner* documentation](http://www.sociodox.com/theminer/)
- [Adobe Max 2011 demo of Monocle profiler](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2011-sneak-peeks/max-2011-sneak-peek-monocle/) Adobe is working on Monocle, a much improved profiler, which was demoed at Max 2011. Release is planned for the end of 2012 (Flash Player "Dolores")
- [Adobe TV: Concurrency in Flash Runtimes](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2011-develop/concurrency-in-flash-runtimes/) (starting with Flash Player 11.4 beta)
- [Adobe TV: Performance-tuning Flex Mobile Applications](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2011-develop/performancetuning-mobile-flex-applications/)
- [Stage3D hardware acceleration](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/stage3d.html)

Much depends on what kind of devices you are targeting, or which features you are using, e.g.

- Mobile vs desktop deployment
- Do you load large amounts of data
- Real-time communication requirements
- Number of visual items or components
- Number of animations / items animated
- Screen resolution (e.g. building applications for Smart TVs with very high resolution)
- Do you use HD video playback
- Video streaming - which quality and resolution are you using

Answer (score 0):

try to use [monocle](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2011-sneak-peeks/max-2011-sneak-peek-monocle/)....is really powerfull